# I am trying to pass a varible as a literal string to a function from JS created inner html

Tags: string, function, arguments

What I am trying to do is to pass a string to the inner html so that it can be a argument in a function.>>>> onclick='deleteme('"+hotlist[i]+"') <<<< is not working. I have to figure out how to turn that variable into a string and put it into the inner html. when I leave the argument blank it actually fires the deleteme() function but then the argument is undefined. I need each argument to be unique for each button created by this loop.

```js
    function myhotlist()
{

var hotlist = document.cookie.split(";");
var text = ""; 

for (i = 0; i < hotlist.length; i++) { 
    text += hotlist[i] + "   <input type='submit' onclick='deleteme('"+hotlist[i]+"') value='delete' ><br>";
 }
document.getElementById("hotrack").innerHTML= text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd best use DOM for this, so you're not overlooking any luring escaping troubles.

Something like this should work:

```
var container = document.createElement('div'), 
    i, el,
    hotlist = document.cookie.split(";");

for (i = 0; i < hotlist.length; i++) {
    el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    el.onclick = function() {
        deleteme(i);
    }
    el.setAttribute('value', "Delete " + i);
    container.appendChild(el);
}

document.body.appendChild(container);
```

Of course, there are legion of libraries out there which can help you with this (ranging from jQuery to React JSX) but if you get the DOM essentials, you really don't need the libraries, and you actually get a better understanding of how JavaScript interacts with visual elements and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks this looks like it will work and it has a different approach which would be good to learn .. ill check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this using DOM as suggested.

```js
 function myhotlist()
{

var hotlist = document.cookie.split(";");
var funname = "";
var newline= new Array();
for (i = 0; i < hotlist.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById("hotrack").innerHTML += hotlist[i];
  newline[i] = document.createElement("input");
  newline[i].setAttribute("type", "submit");
  var namey ="delete"+hotlist[i];
  newline[i].setAttribute("id", namey);
  newline[i].setAttribute("value", "[X]");
  funname = "delme('" + hotlist[i] + "')";
   newline[i].setAttribute("onclick", funname);
  document.getElementById("hotrack").appendChild(newline[i]);
    
    document.getElementById("hotrack").innerHTML += "<br>";
   
 }
}
```